# How can I call an API in a foreach depending on a response of another API in PHP?

Tags: php, api, foreach

I get stuck with the following situation. I have two APIs. I want to call the second one in a "foreach" using the response of the first one called previously outside and before the "foreach" starts.

Why I need this?, because with the first API I get an array of IDs, and for each value I need to include them in the url of the second API. Finally, with both responses and their combinations will insert values in a MySql table.

I tried to call the first API individually and then, tried to use each value of previous response in each iteration of the "foreach" using a second API also individually. Once I tried to run it, execution never ends. After that, I realized that exists curl_multi_XXX functions, but I don´t understand on how to use them in this situation (if applies).

I preferred not to share the specific situation in order to have a template from you and use it in future projects.

I really appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75190473/edit) to at least show pseudo-code, if not a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem you're having.

Comment: For performance reasons, It is usually a very bad idea to run queries, fetch remote files, or access APIs inside a loop. Is there no way you can use the loop to aggregate a collection of data to batch process all at once, so you can just contact each API once?

Comment: Understood!, idea dropped at all. Thanks a lot!